# Detect which item is currently scrolled to in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement an autoplay feature for video items in a RecyclerView (linear vertical layout). I can't figure out how to know when a certain item is currently on/off the screen so I can autoplay/pause the video. If I put the code in onBindViewHolder method all videos start playing simultaniously. Couldn't find a solution by googling it either. Help, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Recyclerview you should rely on your layout manager to give you this information.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager
or
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager

Assign a layout to the RecyclerView when you assign the adapter. Then use it to see what is visible.

[image]

Let me help a bit more with some Psedo Kotlin code for you to help with the player aspect.

Let's pretend you have some object that is bound into each row that can trigger the playing and has a unique ID. Let's call that an ActiveRowPlayer for this example.

NOTE*
If you are using databinding, it is simple to bind your video player playing content to a property in your model that is populating the row, but that's different story for a different post.

You can make an interface like:

```
interface IActivePlayerUpdater{
    fun onUpdateCurrentPlayer
}
```

You can make a helper method like:

in your activity, you can implement an interface like :IActivePlayerUpdater and override the methods for it.

```
override fun onUpdateCurrentPlayer(){
    var activeRowPlayer = recyclerView.layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
    if(activeRowplayer.someID != currentRowPlayer.someID){
        currentRowPlayer.stopPlaying
        currentRowPlayer = activeRowPlayer
        activeRowPlayer.startPlaying
    }
}
```

Then pass it into your adapter and just monitor your onBind method and anytime a new onBind is called that means the content has moved enough to trigger a new row item.

```
MyAdapterConstructor(IActivePlayerUpdater myCallback)

fun recyclerView.onBindMethod(stuffThatComesHere){
    //do normal stuff
    myCallback.onUpdateCurrentPlayer()
}
```

Keep in mind, this is just pseudo to help you on your journey. not intended to be direct copy and paste.

----NOTE* REQUESTED FROM COMMENT TO SUPPLY HOW TO TOUCH VIEWMODEL FROM OUTSIDE OF ADAPTER---

> @Goran, this example I had setup a long time ago to avoid
>   notifyDataSetChanged on selection changed to toggle a checkbox for
>   each item. I eventually moved to a better option, but you asked how do
>   you get the viewmodel, here is a sample. rvCameraRoll was my
>   recyclerView, I was using it to display camera media, but that is not
>   relevant, just focus on getting the viewModel piece.

The only part you should care about is getting the ViewHolder, I just left the rest there in case it helps you with anything else.

```
     int count = rvCameraRoll.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        MediaModelGridAdapter.ViewHolder childRow = (MediaModelGridAdapter.ViewHolder)rvCameraRoll.getChildViewHolder(rvCameraRoll.getChildAt(i));
        if(isVisible) {
            childRow.imgCellSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(getMediaModelList().get(i).getIsSelected()){
                childRow.imgCellSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ap_selected_on);
            }

        }else{
            //check that exists, because after fresh delete list may be short while updating cells
            if(getMediaModelList().size() > i) {
                getMediaModelList().get(i).setIsSelected(false);
            }
            childRow.imgCellSelected.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ap_selected_off);
            childRow.imgCellSelected.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }

    }
```

OLD

leaving this for anyone using a ListView

There is a OnScrollListener for ListView

You can override the

`onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)`

and 
the

`onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)`

this will give you the ListView item that is visible. So by using the onScroll you can detect which items are visible and determine which one to play and stop playing.

if you use with recyclerview
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

Comment: There is no difference. @GoranKovač

Comment: still, these callbacks dont give me any information about visible items, only scroll amount (dx, dy) and scroll state...how does that help me?

Comment: sorry @GoranKovač didn't realize the interface varied on Recyclerview usage, thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer for you with a better solution for your need.

Comment: thanks, that's something, it gives me a visible item...but I still don't understand how to get a callback when an item is completely visible and get the item's coresponding holder to play a video in that callback

Comment: @GoranKovač your question was to know when a certain item was on or off screen. I have provided you that answer. Now you are asking for additional questions. Start a new question if you would like to know how to start playing a video or stop playing for a row item. However, you have everything you need. onScroll will tell you state has changed, also onBindView will tell you new items are moving into view prep. You can always call the first visible item methods i provided you each time new views are bound and determine which to play or pause. You have to keep track of your playing item to stop

Comment: sorry if I sounded ungrateful, I really appreciate all the help you provided - I'm just a bit frustrated with this problem I'm having for 2 days now...thanks for helping a noob out :)

Comment: no problem, i understand. here I'll update the answer one more time to help give you a little guidance in that area as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, that extra guidance really helps to put things into perspective...cheers!

Comment: Still can't figure it out...I managed to get correct item positions but can't get the right ViewHolder to stop playing the video, since only time adapter gives me acces to holders is in onBindViewHolder() method. Is there a way to get the corresponding viewholder by item position?

Comment: Tough to say without knowing your row_layout.xml and your object. If you are using binding, it is super easy, you just bind playing to a boolean in that model and update the model and your done. But if you are relying on touching UI elements to say play/pause, you can get it sure, but can get a little tedious to code that way. It's asking for a lot of boiler plate code in my opinion, but I'll update my answer with some code for touching viewmodels externally

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem. I was trying to get the item via adapter when I should have use the recyclerview itself.

Answer (score 0):

The RecyclerView is only holding the items and the LayoutManager is responsible for displaying the items, so in order to get the ones that are visible to the user, assuming that you use LinearLayoutManager, you should call :
((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
or
((LinearLayoutManager)recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastVisibleItemPosition();